# Eliminating Recursion

Tags: java

I've just been looking at the following piece of code

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final int sizeA = 3;
        final int sizeB = 5;

        final List<int[]> combos = getAllCombinations(sizeA-1, sizeB);

        int counter = 1;
        for(final int[] combo : combos) {
            System.out.println("Combination " + counter);
            System.out.println("--------------");
            for(final int value : combo) {
                System.out.print(value + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            ++counter;
        }

    }

    private static List<int[]> getAllCombinations(final int maxIndex, final int size) {

        if(maxIndex >= size)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The maximum index must be smaller than the array size.");

        final List<int[]> result = new ArrayList<int[]>();

        if(maxIndex == 0) {
            final int[] array = new int[size];
            Arrays.fill(array, maxIndex);
            result.add(array);
            return result;
        }

        //We'll create one array for every time the maxIndex can occur while allowing
        //every other index to appear, then create every variation on that array
        //by having every possible head generated recursively
        for(int i = 1; i < size - maxIndex + 1; ++i) {

            //Generating every possible head for the array
            final List<int[]> heads = getAllCombinations(maxIndex - 1, size - i);

            //Combining every head with the tail
            for(final int[] head : heads) {
                final int[] array = new int[size];
                System.arraycopy(head, 0, array, 0, head.length);
                //Filling the tail of the array with i maxIndex values
                for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
                    array[size - j] = maxIndex;
                result.add(array);
            }

        }

        return result;

    }

}
```

I'm wondering, how do I eliminate recursion from this, so that it returns a single random combination, rather than a list of all possible combinations?

Thanks

Comment: Eliminating recursion and having a single combination as result are two different (independent) tasks. Which one do you want to accomplish? (or both?)

Comment: I want to return a single random combination. But for larger sizes the current program might not be very efficient, hence why I think I need to eliminate recursion too.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956336/turning-a-recursive-function-into-a-for-loop

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496192/eliminating-recursion

Comment: @skaffman your link actually is this question ;-)

Comment: Soo, anyone have any ideas? It's been giving me a headache for ages!

Comment: @skaffman yes, but the OP actually wanted to _eliminate_ recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly your task is as follows: give a random combination of numbers `'0' .. 'sizeA-1'` of length `sizeB` where

1. the combination is sorted
2. each number occurs at least once

i.e. in your example e.g. `[0,0,1,2,2]`.

If you want to have a single combination only I'd suggest another algorithm (pseudo-code):

- Randomly choose the step-up positions (e.g. for sequence `[0,0,1,1,2]` it would be steps (`1->2`) & (`3->4`)) - we need `sizeA-1` steps randomly chosen at `sizeB-1` positions.
- Calculate your target combination out of this vector

A quick-and-dirty implementation in java looks like follows

```
// Generate list 0,1,2,...,sizeB-2 of possible step-positions 
List<Integer> steps = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int h = 0; h < sizeB-1; h++) {
    steps.add(h);
}

// Randomly choose sizeA-1 elements
Collections.shuffle(steps);
steps = steps.subList(0, sizeA - 1);
Collections.sort(steps);

// Build result array
int[] result = new int[sizeB];
for (int h = 0, o = 0; h < sizeB; h++) {
    result[h] = o;
    if (o < steps.size() && steps.get(o) == h) {
        o++;
    }
}
```

Note: this can be optimized further - the first step generates a random permutation and later strips this down to desired size. Therefore it is just for demonstration purpose that the algorithm itself works as desired.

Comment: @Howard, do you have a compilable version? I just want to see how this runs. When I tried running yours in my code, it did not work correctly.

Comment: @Pandy Actually it's compiling when you have specified `sizeA` and `sizeB`. You can find the complete runnable version [here](http://ideone.com/BEH5O).

Comment: @Howard, how would you modify this so that the sizeA no longer has to be smaller than the sizeB, (duplicating values if it is smaller) and the size of the array returned is 2 x sizeB?

Comment: @Pandy What do you mean by "duplicating values"? Please specify **exactly** what combinations you want to have.

Comment: What I mean is, if you have [0,1,1,2]. In which case sizeA < sizeB the array returned will then become:
[0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2] size B is double the size, and the values have been duplicated and placed next to each other.
In the case where sizeB < sizeA. So say sizeB is 4. We will return an array double the size of sizeB, with the same conditions
1) Each array is sorted
2) Each number occurs at least once
so a result such as : [0,1,1,2,3,4,5,5]

Comment: We leave this as an exercise for the reader (hint: In the first case double each element in the result array, in the second just set `sizeB<-2*sizeB`).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be homework.  Without giving you code, here's an idea.  Call `getAllCombinations`, store the result in a `List`, and return a value from a random index in that list.  As Howard pointed out in his comment to your question, eliminating recursion, and returning a random combination are separate tasks.

Comment: This isn't a homework. I've tried doing something similar to that in the main method essentially something like this:   final List<int[]> combos = getAllCombinations(sizeA-1, sizeB);
        
 /*       int listSize = combos.size();
        int item = new Random().nextInt(listSize); 
        int i = 0;
        for(final int[] combo : combos)
        {
            if (i == item)
                System.out.println(combo);
           // i = i + 1;
        }*/

But it did not work

Comment: Why do you have if(i==item) ??  And why do it in a for loop?

Comment: It will just not return any array. I thought it would be the best way to do it, to match the random number with the the index position in the list, but I may be wrong...

Comment: Remove the if, and re-run it.  Try attaching with a debugger and seeing why it returns a null list.