# Resolving StackOverFlowException in C++

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I am trying to write a program for selection sort of the elements an array in C++ (VS2010) using recursion. The program works without any issues for for smaller arrays where the size of the array is less than 10 when I increase the size of the array to 10000 I am facing stackoverflow exception. How do I go about resolving this?

Thank you for the answers so far. My idea is not to sort the array but to sort a large array using recursion and the hit a stackoverflow exception. My main idea behind this exercise is to learn ways to resolve the stackoverflow exception rather than sorting the array.

```
selectionSortRecursive(int a[], int startindex, int endindex)
{
    if (startindex<endindex)
    {
        int s = startindex;
        for (int index=startindex+1;index<endindex;index++)
        {
            if (a[s]>a[index])
                s=index;
        }
        if (s>startindex)
        {
            a[s]=a[startindex]+a[s];
            a[startindex]=a[s]-a[startindex];
            a[s]=a[s]-a[startindex];
        }
        selectionSortRecursive(a, startindex+1, endindex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to show us a code sample?

Comment: How can we know unless you send any piece of code?

Comment: The recursion is the reason for the stackoverflow. Show us some code, maybe something can be optimized.

Comment: You're best best is probably to rewrite your method using a loop instead of recursion. If you can rewrite your recursive method to be tail recursive, then it's easy to rewrite it again using a loop. Check out [Turning a Recursive Function into a For Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956336/turning-a-recursive-function-into-a-for-loop)

Comment: Why do you have recursion in such a simple sort? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort.

Comment: recursion for selection sort? LOL! Since it is a toy implementation of a toy algorithm, I'll not bother with it if I were you.

Comment: As an aside, you definitely don't want to use selection sort for an array of 10,000 elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either increase the size of the stack (which can be done with the `STACK` linker option) or -- and this is a much better option -- improve or replace your algorithm. It sounds like a recursive algorithm may not be suitable for the kind of data you need to process, but maybe you can improve things by using fewer local variables and/or parameters in each method invocation, to make the stack frames smaller.

Answer (score 2):

You are either using a great deal of local storage or your recursive algorithms explodes memory usage by subsequent calls. In either case probably an iterative solution would solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables, as you may know, are kept on the stack.

When a function recurses, local variables from each call remain on the stack for as long as their respective functions execute.  If you recurse too much, the build-up will be too great and you will likely end up with a stack overflow exception, like you're getting, or a segmentation fault, where the stack overflows into protected memory.

This is fundamental, and there is no way around it other than to increase your available memory or to rewrite your function to be iterative.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive approach will take lot of stack space; instead of it, we can use a `for` loop to implement it:

```
void sort_array(int a[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++) 
    {
        int min=i;
        for(int j=i+1; j<size; j++)
        {
            if(a[j]<a[min])
                min=j;
        }
        if(min!=i)
        {
            int temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[min];
            a[min]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

This code might work for you.