# How to turn java for loops into recursion?

Tags: java, loops

I have three for loops, and I wish to turn them into recursive method because I want to do this for any amount of for loops. I searched online, but nobody seems to have exactly what I need, for example this guy turns recursion into for loops
[Turning a recursive function into a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956336/turning-a-recursive-function-into-a-for-loop)
Code:

```
    int x = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < x; k++){
                list.add(array[i] + array[j] + array[k]);
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to make them recursive? Java isn't a functional language - it would only make it slower and harder to read.

Comment: recursive functions are functions that call themselves. You're not calling any functions which call themselves... You'd end up with probably 2x the code just to handle the recursion infrastructure, with basically nothing to show for it.

Comment: Loops can do anything that recursive methods can do, and in Java, they do those things faster.

Comment: According to the code shown so far, and the statement *"I want to do this for any amount of for loops"*, one has to assume that the intention is to find a generic pattern for handling these kinds of loops for an *arbitrary nesting depth*. A recursive solution is in most cases much more elegant there. But to rule out this one: Are you ONLY trying to find all combinations of 3 (or more) elements? Or are you really looking for a "generic" conversion rule from loops to recursive funtions?

Answer (score 2):

Think of a `for` loop as a little anonymous function that takes the loop index value as a parameter. In order to start the next iteration of the loop, the function can return a call to itself with a new value for the loop index parameter.

Like this:

```
Object loop(int i, Object data) {
    if (i > 0) {
        return loop(i - 1, evolve(data));
    } else {
        return data;
    }
}
```

That's the same as this:

```
for ( ; i > 0; i--) {
    data = evolve(data);
}
```

In some languages, particularly Scheme, and who knows maybe Java 8 or 9, the compiler is guaranteed to compile a recursive function such as the function `loop` above just the same as it compiles the `for` loop above.

In other languages, including the current and past versions of Java, nearly all compilers will make an executable that builds a big call stack. When the call stack is large it may even overflow the permitted size and crash the program.

Answer (score 2):

Haters aside, let's do this! <sup>**[1]**</sup>

Given:

```
int x = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < x; k++){
      list.add(array[i] + array[j] + array[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Let's consider that *each loop* is it's own recursive function - as this makes the recurrence cases much easier! This is also the only "non-thinking" method I know of to turn the loops into recursion. The recursive depth will be limited to `3*x => i+j+k` so it's "fairly safe" for a smallish<sup>**[2]**</sup> `x`.

In Java it requires a separate method for each loop to encode this structure. (In a language with higher-order functions these three functions might be abstractly combined .. but not in Java [7].)

```
void loopI(int i) {
    if (i < x) {
      loopJ(0);   // "start j loop"
      loopI(i++); // "next i loop" / recurrence case
    }
    // "end loop" / base case
}

void loopJ(int j) {
    if (j < x) {
      loopK(0);
      loopJ(j++);
    }
}

void loopK(int k) {
   if (k < x) {
     list.add(array[i] + array[j] + array[k]);
     loopK(k++);
   }
}

// do it!
loopI(0);
```

All of these *could* be combined into a single recursive function, but that makes handling the recurrence cases a bit tougher as "thinking" and additional conditionals (or mod expressions, perhaps) are required to advance the state.

Here is an example of a *combined* recursive function (this is incorrect when `x` is 0). Unlike the three method approach above, the stack depth will grow to `x^3 => i*j*k`. This *will easily kill Java's recursion limits* - even for smallish values of `x`- as Java [7] *doesn't* have [tail-call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

```
void loop(int i, int j, int k) {        
    list.add(array[i] + array[j] + array[k]);

    // advance states
    k++;
    if (k == x) { k = 0; j++; }
    if (j == x) { j = 0; i++; }
    if (i == x) { i = 0; }

    // terminate on all wrap-around
    if (i == 0 && j == 0 && k == 0) { return; }

    // recurse
    loop(i, j, k);
}
```

---

<sup>**[1]**</sup> YMMV, for theoretical purposes only - I love recursion, but it's not suited for *this case* in Java.

<sup>**[2]**</sup> For some value of "smallish". See how deep your stack can go!

Comment: Sometimes the correct answer is "don't do it" ;)

Comment: @JonatanHedborg This is a theoretical answer to a theoretical question :)