# fixing a recursive backtracking algorithm code

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

i need to find an algorithm that use a recursive backtracking algorithm which will print me all the possible compositions to `x1+x2+x3` to be equals to the number.
lets say the input number is 4 so the method will print me 3 results:

```
1 1 2
1 2 1
1 1 2
```

......
The code:

```
public class getResult

 public static void results(int n)
    {
    int[] history= new int[3];
    results(n,history,0);
    }
    private static void results(int n,int[] history,int i)
    {
    if(n==0)
    {
    printHistory(history,0,i);
    System.out.println();
    }
    if`(n>0&&i<3)`
    {
    history[i]=1;

    //insert 1 to history in order to go back in case of wrong 
    // way using backtracking.
    results(n-1,history,i+1);//calling the function again, with n-1 , backup history, history[i+1]`
    history[i]=2;
    results(n-2,history,i+1);
        history[i]=3;
    results(n-3,history,i+1);
    //.....9
    }
    }
    private static void printHistory(int[] history,int from,int to)
    {
    if(from<to)
    {
    System.out.print(history[from]+"\t");
    printHistory(history,from+1,to);
    }
    }
    }
```

I have 2 questions:
1. how  can I print only the results that concludes `x1,x2,x3`.
Because for now, if i try to input `num=5` it will print me the following results:

```
1   1   3   
1   2   2   
1   3   1   
1   4   
2   1   2   
2   2   1   
2   3   
3   1   1   
3   2   
4   1   
5
```

And i want to get the results that only conclude 3 numbers(without for example the results: 5, 4 1, 3 2, 2 3)..

2.Is there a way to write these lines better:

```
 history[i]=1;
results(n-1,history,i+1)`;`
```

instead every time to copy the code and subtract a number manually from the number?(The results should pass all over the numbers between 1 to 9)

Thank you all for help, if something isn't clear i would like to help :)

Comment: To print only 3 you can put `n == 0 && i == 3` instead of  `n==0` where you print the result

Comment: @ButiriDan you are right! Thank you, and what about the other question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and I can't seem to pick it as a "Migrate..." reason

Comment: @ButiriDan But i am not allowed to use loop if i didn't mentioned.
is there  a way to write it  with a recursion call?

Comment: @Jordan_boy the recursive call is still there

Comment: @ButiriDan yes, but the "while" keyword is not allowed, i need to try to do the loop using recursion. can you help with this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Your code is difficult to read, and I *think* it has syntax errors.  As posted, it will produce no output, let alone the output you claim.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question you just have to extract the generic formula and use a loop

```
private static void results(int n, int[] history, int i) {
    if (n == 0 && i == 3) {
        printHistory(history, 0, i);
        System.out.println();
    }
    if (n > 0 && i < 3) {
        int LIMIT = 4;
        int step = 0;

        while (step < LIMIT) {
            history[i] = ++step;
            results(n - step, history, i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Result

```
1   1   3   
1   2   2   
1   3   1   
2   1   2   
2   2   1   
3   1   1
```

Comment: Maybe this post will help you to replace that while [Turning a recursive function into a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956336/turning-a-recursive-function-into-a-for-loop)